# InnoDB: preallocating 147456 bytes for file XXX.ibd failed with error 2

Tags: docker, mariadb, innodb, hyper-v, wsl-2

I'm using official MariadDB 10.7 docker image, Windows 10. Had this error started today that kept repeating, tried everything:

```
- mysqlcheck -Ar
- delete docker image with all the data
- chkdsk -F
- dump and restore of table
- change MariaDB version
- different PC configs (nvme -> SSD)
```

Comment: Sounds like the disk space allocated for the VM is too small.

Comment: Is there any other switch apart from "storage-opts": ["size=50GB"] to control this space?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After long long reading of every related bug on MariaDB bug trackers I did one change in Docker environment:

```
- disable WSL2, switch to Hyper-V
```

And voila, started working.

Now, interesting part is, coworker had same problem, but had WSL2 already disabled, and his problem was fixed with ENABLING WSL2.

So I guess, while changing operation between WSL2 and Hyper-V, something is done, that gets corrupted while using image and it reset with this switch.

ATM I don't have time to switch back to WSL2 to confirm my assumption. When I find some time, I'll update this post.

UPDATE:
couldn't find the solution with container's config, so I tried older versions of MariaDB docker container and it started working on version 10.3.9. For now, I'm going to be using this version until I find some more time to go to MariaDB's Jira and report error there.

Comment: Rolling back to version 10.3.9 is the only thing worked for me! Thanks )

Comment: As @UmurKaragöz rolling back to version 10.3.9 solved the problem, thanks. Did not test wsl solution. In version 10.3.38 the problem still exist.

Comment: @SubjectX did you open the bug?

Comment: No, I didnt have time at the time of this bug, we simply are using specific version that works.

Comment: In my case, the problem where mounted windows folders

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when running MariaDB 10.6.3 with the following docker run command:

```
docker run -d --name mariadb --restart always -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=develop -e MYSQL_DATABASE=YourDatabaseHere -e MYSQL_USER=develop -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=develop -v C:\some-path\dev-data\mysql:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 mariadb:10.6.3
```

I narrowed it down to an issue with the mapped volume. I resolved the issue by using a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/):

```
docker volume create myvolume
```

With the volume created, my new docker run looked like:

```
docker run -d --name mariadb --restart always -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=develop -e MYSQL_DATABASE=YourDatabaseHere -e MYSQL_USER=develop -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=develop -v myvolume:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 mariadb:10.6.3
```